# getting 10-15 seconds to execute query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have around 2 page of query, which is simple no complicated logic for that, but when i run that query in sql server, it takes 10-15 sec to execute, i have applied all the index which is require for that query, still it is taking to load, can anyone please tell me what i can do something more which helps me to execute query faster, here is my query

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2016-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2016_05, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2016_05, 
(COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2016_05, 
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2016-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2016_05, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2016-05') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2016_05, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2016-05') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2016_05, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2016_05, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2016_05, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2016-05' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2016_05, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-05') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2016_05, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-05') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2016_05, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-05') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2016_05, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-05') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2016_05, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-05') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2016_05, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-05') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2016_05, 
COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2016-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2016_05, 
SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-05') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2016_05, 
SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2016-05') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2016_05 ,
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2016-06') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2016_06, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-06') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2016_06, 
(COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-06') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2016_06, 
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2016-06') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2016_06, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2016-06') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2016_06, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2016-06') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2016_06, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-06') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2016_06, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-06') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2016_06, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2016-06' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2016_06, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-06') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2016_06, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-06') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2016_06, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-06') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2016_06, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-06') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2016_06, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-06') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2016_06, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-06') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2016_06, 
COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2016-06') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2016_06, 
SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-06') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2016_06, 
SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2016-06') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2016_06 ,
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2016-07') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2016_07, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-07') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2016_07, 
(COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-07') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2016_07, 
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2016-07') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2016_07, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2016-07') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2016_07, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2016-07') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2016_07,
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-07') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2016_07, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-07') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2016_07, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2016-07' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2016_07, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-07') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2016_07, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-07') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2016_07, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-07') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2016_07, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-07') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2016_07, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-07') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2016_07, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-07') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2016_07, 
COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2016-07') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2016_07, 
SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-07') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2016_07, 
SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2016-07') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2016_07 ,
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2016-08') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2016_08, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-08') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2016_08, 
(COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-08') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2016_08, 
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2016-08') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2016_08, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2016-08') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2016_08, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2016-08') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2016_08, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-08') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2016_08, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-08') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2016_08, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2016-08' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2016_08, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-08') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2016_08, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-08') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2016_08, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-08') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2016_08, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-08') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2016_08, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-08') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2016_08, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-08') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2016_08, 
COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2016-08') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2016_08, 
SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-08') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2016_08, 
SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2016-08') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2016_08 ,
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2016-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2016_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2016_09, 
(COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2016_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2016-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2016_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2016-09') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2016_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2016-09') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2016_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2016_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2016_09, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2016-09' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2016_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-09') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2016_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-09') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2016_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-09') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2016_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-09') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2016_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-09') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2016_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-09') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2016_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2016-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2016_09, 
SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-09') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2016_09, 
SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2016-09') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2016_09 ,
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2016-10') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2016_10, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-10') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2016_10, 
(COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-10') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2016_10, 
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2016-10') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2016_10, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2016-10') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2016_10, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2016-10') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2016_10, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-10') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2016_10, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-10') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2016_10, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2016-10' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2016_10, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-10') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2016_10, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-10') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2016_10, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-10') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2016_10, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-10') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2016_10, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-10') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2016_10, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-10') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2016_10, 
COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2016-10') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2016_10, 
SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-10') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2016_10, 
SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2016-10') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2016_10 ,
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2016-11') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2016_11, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-11') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2016_11, 
(COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-11') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2016_11, 
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2016-11') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2016_11, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2016-11') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2016_11, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2016-11') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2016_11, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-11') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2016_11, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-11') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2016_11, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2016-11' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2016_11, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-11') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2016_11, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-11') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2016_11, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-11') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2016_11, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-11') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2016_11, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-11') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2016_11, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-11') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2016_11, 
COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2016-11') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2016_11, 
SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-11') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2016_11, 
SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2016-11') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2016_11 ,
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2016-12') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2016_12, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-12') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2016_12, 
(COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2016-12') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2016_12, 
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2016-12') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2016_12, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2016-12') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2016_12, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2016-12') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2016_12, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-12') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2016_12, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-12') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2016_12, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2016-12' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2016_12, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2016-12') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2016_12, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-12') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2016_12, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-12') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2016_12, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-12') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2016_12, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-12') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2016_12, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2016-12') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2016_12, 
COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2016-12') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2016_12, 
SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2016-12') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2016_12, 
SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2016-12') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2016_12 ,
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2017-01') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2017_01, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-01') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2017_01, 
(COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-01') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2017_01,
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2017-01') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2017_01, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2017-01') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2017_01, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2017-01') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2017_01, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-01') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2017_01, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-01') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2017_01, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2017-01' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2017_01, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-01') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2017_01, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-01') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2017_01,
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-01') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2017_01, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-01') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2017_01, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-01') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2017_01, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-01') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2017_01, COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2017-01') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2017_01, SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-01') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2017_01, SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2017-01') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2017_01 ,COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2017-02') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2017_02, COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-02') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2017_02, (COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-02') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2017_02, COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2017-02') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2017_02, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2017-02') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2017_02, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2017-02') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2017_02, COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-02') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2017_02, COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-02') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2017_02, COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2017-02' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2017_02, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-02') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2017_02, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-02') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2017_02, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-02') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2017_02, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-02') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2017_02, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-02') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2017_02, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-02') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2017_02, COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2017-02') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2017_02, SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-02') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2017_02, SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2017-02') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2017_02 ,COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2017-03') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2017_03, COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-03') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2017_03, (COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-03') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2017_03, COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2017-03') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2017_03, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2017-03') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2017_03, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2017-03') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2017_03, COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-03') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2017_03, COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-03') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2017_03, COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2017-03' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2017_03, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-03') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2017_03, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-03') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2017_03, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-03') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2017_03, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-03') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2017_03, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-03') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2017_03, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-03') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2017_03, COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2017-03') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2017_03, SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-03') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2017_03, SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2017-03') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2017_03 ,COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2017-04') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2017_04, COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-04') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2017_04, (COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-04') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2017_04, COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2017-04') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2017_04, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2017-04') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2017_04, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2017-04') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2017_04, COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2017_04, COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2017_04, COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2017-04' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2017_04, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2017_04, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2017_04, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2017_04, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2017_04, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2017_04, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2017_04, COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2017_04, SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2017_04, SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2017-04') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2017_04 ,COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2017-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2017_05, COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2017_05, (COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END)) as RecertPer1_2017_05, COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2017-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2017_05, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2017-05') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2017_05, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2017-05') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2017_05, COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2017_05, COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2017_05, COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2017-05' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2017_05, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-05') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2017_05, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-05') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2017_05, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-05') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2017_05, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-05') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2017_05, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-05') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2017_05, ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-05') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2017_05, COUNT(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and LUPA = '0' and MonthEnd='2017-05') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Lupa_Closed_2017_05, SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-05') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2017_05, SUM(CASE when (MonthEnd='2017-05') then NonTHEp ELSE NULL END) as NonTHEp_2017_05 
FROM tb_Episode 
WHERE CustID = 27 AND PayerType = 'EP' AND BranchID IN (238,239,240,241)
```

Comment: Post your indexes and query plan as well.

Comment: What happens when you delete half of the columns?

Comment: In this table  104 columns, it is taking less time, if i delete half columns

Comment: I have applied index for the select column and in where condition column

Comment: I mean what happens if you reduce the number columns in the select list to half. Could post the processing time of reduced SQL?

Comment: @RadimBača it is taking less time

Comment: Why on earth are you calculating so many different periods as separate columns?  Just put the `MonthEnd` column as a `group by` value and run this query in a set based manner.

Comment: Without even attempting to get into the details of your query, I can already assert that there is a very serious design issue with the DB you are using. You are `COUNT` ing or `ROUND` ing all fields...Good luck!!!

Comment: Try to split this query into 2 and see which runs slower. + should provide some insight about data. How many rows, indexes, partitions, table structures, etc.